# How to add additional fixed bar to Twitter's Bootstrap navbar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

See picture below - this additional bar should always go with original bar (`.navbar .navbar-fixed-top`).

[image: example picture]

Comment: A sub menu? There's an example of this in the doc's html. Although not part of bootstrap, it's pretty straight forward (you'll have to look at the .subnav tags in the docs.css file too). You can easily duplicate this for your own use.

Comment: No, it is not about sub menu. See what I've shown on the picture (where "some dynamic text.." is shown). It should be always shown.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use modified `.subnav-fixed` class. Needed modifications:

```
height: auto;
left: auto;
right: 100px;
width: 300px;
```

bootstrap.css doesn't contain `.subnav` and `.subnav-fixed` classes. You can find them [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/docs.css).

Comment: How should I use it? Please check what I've tried - http://jsbin.com/azirid/edit#preview

Comment: The bootstrap.css doesn't contain .subnav and .subnav-fixed classes. You must to add additional file http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/docs.css

Comment: Thanks, it works now - http://jsbin.com/azirid/3/edit#preview. But I don't want to use the whole `docs.css`, should I take just `.subnav` from this file?

Comment: Yes, you can do so. But not just `.subnav`, `.subnav-fixed` also.

Comment: btw, why should I have `.subnav`? Where is it used?

Comment: It isn't nessesary for you to use `.subnav`. It defines background, border and sizes.

Comment: link no longer contains .subnav class

Comment: I don't know if it is the good .subnav but I have found a link : https://gist.github.com/thomaspark/4394162